# mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'user_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/my_web_site/public_html/index.php

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I'm trying to host a website , and it's giving me the error

> mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'agtmaroc_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/my_web_site/public_html/index.php

I created a DB and a User added the user to the database with all privileges 
then i used the username / dbname and password in this script

```
$conn=\mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname") or trigger_error(mysqli_error(db_name).E_USER_ERROR);
```

Comment: seems your password is wrong

Comment: i tryed modifing it many times and it did not work , it's correct without any special caractere

Comment: Did you check the username and the password is correct